# Best Sites for Reading/Listening to Great Divrei Torah

Tags: torah-study, internet, product-recommendation

What are some good sites for Divrei Torah, and what are the strengths of each?

Answer (score 9):

[YUTorah](http://yutorah.org) has a tremendous wealth of audio and text lectures from YU faculty, alumni, students, and events. The site is well-organized, so you can search for and find material on pretty much any topic you can think of. You can also subscribe to a speaker's materials as a podcast and get automatically updated each time there's new material. I can't recommend this website highly enough.

Comment: YUTorah.org is great for its wealth of material in different media.

Answer (score 4):

A thought provoking parsha analysis, coming from an academic standpoint can be found here: 
http://parsha.blogspot.com/

The DovBear blog has some interesting notes in his ParshaNotes postings:
http://dovbear.blogspot.com/search/label/Parsha%20notes

The Hirhurim blog has a weekly Parsha Round Up which summarizes online divrei torah from many sites:
http://www.torahmusings.com/

Comment: DovBear's notes are good.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out http://www.revach.net/shiur/

Answer (score 2):

Amazing Dibre Torah are given at [LearnTorah.com](http://learntorah.com) by Rabbi Eli Mansour Shelit"a. The strenghs of his Divre Torah are that they are something you won't find anywhere else with his unique style and interesting Hiddushim.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know who he is, but he's been on here. His DT's are thought provoking and good to say over.

http://havolim.blogspot.com/

Comment: _Nichnas yayin yatza sod_?

Comment: Eliezer Eisenberg here. Havolim is my blog. Thank you for your nice words! I used to post anonymously, but having married off all my children, I now use my real name. My talent is stimulating excellent contributions and criticism from my readers, which I then incorporate into the posts. It's crowd-sourced Torah, and sometimes, amazing things develop.

Comment: I also read Havolim. Good stuff...

Comment: @EliezerEisenberg Hi welcome to Mi Yodeya! Are these two user accounts yours? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/373/barzilai http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1121/barzilai If you want I can merge them together. I hope you stick around and contribute!

Answer (score 2):

[The Israel Koschitzky Virtual Beit Midrash](http://vbm-torah.org) is from Yeshivat Har Etzion.  I recommend it.

Comment: @msh210 Why the rollback?

Comment: The edit I rolled back changed the post significantly for no good reason I could see.

Comment: @msh210 What did it change? I added the title of the organization and made it one sentence. What's so significant about that?

Comment: (a) The tone of the original answer was that of a fact and then a recommendation. As edited to one sentence, the recommendation loses its oomph/stress. (IMO.) (b) The answer said the site's from the _y'shiva_, not that it's run by it. The answerer may have meant that the content is _sheurim_ from the _y'shiva_, or any one of a number of things, without meaning that the _y'shiva_ runs the site, which is what the emendation said.

Comment: @msh210 a) I disagree. b) I hereby testify that my version is accurate. If AdamMosheh did not know for sure, then I imagine he is glad to receive my new information regarding the administrative setup of the VBM.

Comment: How about: I recommend the [Virtual Beit Midrash](http://www.vbm-torah.org) from Yeshivat Har Etzion. AdamMosheh can you confirm this is not distorting your intention?

Comment: it is okay as is.  thanks for your concern. and thanks for adding the hyperlink

Answer (score 1):

A Broad based extensive Listing [Here](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/index.htm).The Best in My Humble opinion is the 
[Parsha Potpourri.](http://parshapotpourri.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 1):

These are two excellent sites for creative, thoughtful and clear ideas.

[Yeshiva B'nei Torah](http://www.ybt.org/)
[Mesora.org](http://www.mesora.org/)

Answer (score 1):

[DafYomi.org](http://dafyomi.org/) is good for Daf Yomi or just looking something up. The day's Daf shows up by default, and every Daf is available for reading on demand. You can also download podcasts of each Daf individually or by Masechta.
R' Dovid Grossman's style might leave something to be desired for some, but you can't beat a fully explained Daf in 30-45 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.torahanytime.com/   has great shiurim (videos of the shiur as well)

http://www.simpletoremember.com/   is similar

Comment: Thanks. Anything you can add about why you're recommending them will help others to evaluate your recommendation and will thus boost the value of your answer. Welcome to the site; I hope you stick around and enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

[Kol Halashon.com](http://KolHalashon.com)

The biggest repository of Torah recordings in multiple Languages.

[TorahAnytime.com](http://Torahanytime.com)

The largest collection of Video shiurim from a wide variety of speakers.

[Torah.org](http://Torah.org)

Great articles and essays on the Parsha and other topics.

[TorahDownloads.com](http://Torahdownloads.com)

Free shiurim and downloads of many famous and prominent speakers.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.theshmuz.com/ by Rabbi Ben Tzion Shafier

lots of well prepared and thought provoking shiurim